# Obscure/archaic/unusual English word-of-the-day RSS feed?

Tags: vocabulary, online-resources

I seek to embiggen my lexicon. Does anyone know of an obscure/archaic/unusual English word-of-the-day (with authoritative (preferably OED) definition) RSS feed?

- I've found the [OED WotD](http://www.oed.com/rss/wordoftheday) feed, but a fleet survey shows it contains generally everyday language.
- The [Phrontistery](http://phrontistery.info) is interesting, but it appears to be dead, and doesn't feature a feed of words.
- [Wordsmith's *A Word A Day*](http://wordsmith.org/words)  comes close, with some quite rare words. Anything else like this?

Comment: "Help me learn English" questions are generally considered off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

You could subscribe to Michael Quinion's magazine [here](http://www.worldwidewords.org/). That's a weekly, though, although it does have plenty of rare words.

Comment: Quinuin's World Wide Words also has a [daily RSS feed](http://www.worldwidewords.org/rss/wordfile.xml) which features a mix of rare and common words.